# DataSet Updation Fails

Tags: c#, dataset

I am trying to update a modified dataset as given below. I am getting the error. How can I correct the issue?

*An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: Update unable to find TableMapping['Table'] or DataTable 'Table'.*

```
string strAccessConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Program Files\\ASWorx Products\\ASWorx200\\Database\\GemDatabase.mdb";
string strAccessSelect = "SELECT * FROM VariableTable";

// Create the dataset and add the Categories table to it:
DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
OleDbConnection myAccessConn = new OleDbConnection(strAccessConn);            
OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(strAccessSelect, myAccessConn);
OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(myAccessCommand);
myAccessConn.Open();
myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "VariableTable");

DataRowCollection dra = myDataSet.Tables["VariableTable"].Rows;
foreach (DataRow dr in dra)
{
    dr[1] = "SV";
    break;
}
myDataAdapter.Update(myDataSet);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [OleDbCommandBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommandbuilder.aspx) object - which generates single-table commands.

```
OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(strAccessSelect, myAccessConn);
OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(myAccessCommand);
OleDbCommandBuilder cmd=new OleDbCommandBuilder(myDataAdapter);

myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "VariableTable");
..
```

To udate Dataset result,

```
myDataAdapter.Update(myDataSet,"VariableTable");
```

Comment: I am getting the error ' Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information'

Comment: Set/add primary key to the VariableTable table.